# Two Way Encryption of Data PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I am storing sensitive information of users in a database. (address, telephone, child, child school, dob).

I need to have these encrypted in the database but I need to display the plain text on the webpage at times like in the admin section.

I looked in mcrypt but apprantly is going to be deprecated. So I am really stuck here.

Help please!

Comment: Usually implementing encryption at a single point inside a web application is an approach that leads to a false sense if security. Why do you have to encrypt that data inside the database but not elsewhere? Is your database public readable? Note that obviously all required data to decrypt that data has to be present inside your php script. So where is a protection in that setup?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Use [base64_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [base64_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) here.